# How to create maven dependency in java?

Tags: maven

How to create maven dependency in java?
what are the benefits of maven?
what is the role of pom.xml?

mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get
-DrepoUrl=http://download.java.net/maven/2/ -Dartifact=robo-guice:robo-guice:0.4-SNAPSHO

Comment: please any body can tell me that how maven dependency created in customize way?

Answer (score 0):

1. mvn install
   Download the “kaptcha“, extract it and copy the kaptcha-version.jar to somewhere else, for example, c drive. Issue following command :
2. pom.xml
   After installed, just declares the kaptcha coordinate in pom.xml.
3. Done
   Build it, now the "kaptcha" jar is able to retrieve from your Maven local repository.
   link :-http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/